# C# type conversion: Explicit cast exists but throws a conversion error?

Tags: c#, dictionary, type-conversion, ienumerable, hashset

I learned that `HashSet` implements the `IEnumerable` interface. Thus, it is possible to implicitly cast a `HashSet` object into `IEnumerable`:

```
HashSet<T> foo = new HashSet<T>();
IEnumerable<T> foo2 = foo; // Implicit cast, everything fine.
```

This works for nested generic types, too:

```
HashSet<HashSet<T>> dong = new HashSet<HashSet<T>>();
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> dong2 = dong; // Implicit cast, everything fine.
```

At least that's what I thought. But if I make a `Dictionary`, I run into a problem:

```
IDictionary<T, HashSet<T>> bar = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>();
IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> bar2 = bar; // compile error
```

The last line gives me the following compile error (Visual Studio 2015):

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>
> `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<T, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>>` to
> `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<T, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>>`.
>
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

But if I do the cast by writing

```
IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> bar2 = (IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>>) bar;
```

then I get an invalid cast exception at runtime.

Two questions:

- How do I solve this? Is the only way to iterate over the keys and build up a new dictionary bit by bit?
- Why do I get this problem in the first place, even though`HashSet` does implement the `IEnumerable` interface?

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt654060.aspx). `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` isn't. It's the *outer* types where this is important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that the value in `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not [co-variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt654055.aspx) (and nor is the key, for the same reasons). If it were allowed to be, then this code would compile, but *has* to result in an exception:

```
IDictionary<T, HashSet<T>> foo = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>();
IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> bar = foo;
foo.Add(key, new List<T>());
```

You'd think adding a `List<T>` would work, as it would compile given the value type is supposedly `IEnumerable<T>`.  It can't succeed, though, as the *actual* value type is `HashSet<T>`.

So, yes: the only way is to create a new dictionary.

```
var bar = foo.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.AsEnumerable());
```

Answer (score 3):

> How do I solve this? Is the only way to iterate over the keys and
>   build up a new dictionary bit by bit?

It may not be the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
IDictionary<T, HashSet<T>> bar = new Dictionary<T, HashSet<T>>();
IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> bar2 = bar.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => (IEnumerable<T>)y.Value);
```

The reason why the Dictionary cast isn't working is because `IEnumerable` is co-variant, note `<out T>` in the declaration

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

`IDictionary` isn't.

```
public interface IDictionary<TKey, TValue> : ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable
```

You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx