# Flexible use of IDictionary (with interfaces)

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, type-conversion

I'm trying to flexibly use the `IDictionary` interface in one of my methods but because of limitations regarding conversion (see [C# type conversion: Explicit cast exists but throws a conversion error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38503311/5333340) ), its use is very limited to me. I'd like to know if there is some workaround.

This is my concrete problem:
I have a method that takes a mapping that maps every key to an IEnumerable of other keys. It also takes one key as input. What it does is to find a closure set/hull of the given key regarding the mapping:

```
public static ISet<T> GetClosureSet(T element, IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> elementToCollectionMap)
{
    ISet<T> closure = new HashSet<T>();
    closure.Add(element);
    closure.UnionWith(elementToCollectionMap[element]);

    int count = 0;
    while (count != closure.Count)
    {
        count = closure.Count;
        foreach (T elem in new HashSet<T>(closure))
            closure.UnionWith(elementToCollectionMap[elem]);
    }

    return closure;
}
```

Example of such a mapping of type `IDictionary<double, IEnumerable<double>>`:

```
1 -> [2, 3, 4]
2 -> [3, 7]
3 -> [3]
4 -> [] // empty enumerable, i.e. array of length 0
5 -> [6]
6 -> [6]
7 -> []
```

If I put the key `1` and this mapping into my method, I will get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]`: first `1` and its image `[2, 3, 4]` are put together into the closure set. Then the images of `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` are added as well, so we get `7` as well (as element of the image of `2`). In the next step, all images of `1`, `2`, `3`
, `4`, `7` are added, but they are already in there. Thus, the method ends and returns.

As you see, this is a very abstract method that does not care what the values really are. It only needs the values to be `IEnumerable<T>` to be able to call `UnionWith`.

But now I want to be able to use the method whenever I have a mapping from keys to some sort of collections of keys!

I have some places in my code where I define

```
IDictionary<MyType, HashSet<MyType>> foo = new Dictionary<MyType, HashSet<MyType>>();
```

and

```
IDictionary<MyType, List<MyType>> bar = new Dictionary<MyType, List<MyType>>();
```

and need them to really be `IDictionary<MyType, HashSet<MyType>>` and `IDictionary<MyType, List<MyType>>` because I need some functionality of `HashSet` and `List` other than that provided by `IEnumerable`. Only later I want to get the closures. But as it is now, I cannot give `foo` and `bar` as input to my method - I need to create new dictionaries from them to fit the type.

Any ideas on how to solve the problem (I do not consider "creating a new dictionary to fit the type" a solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is to make a slight change to your public API.  Fundamentally `GetClosureSet` doesn't need a mapping of all keys to a sequence of values for that key, it just needs an operation to get all of the values for a given key:

```
public static ISet<T> GetClosureSet(
    T element, 
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
```

The caller can implement that method in any number of ways, one of which is performing a lookup in a dictionary that they have.  This actually makes your method even *more* general, as it allows you to perform this operation on different types of graphs that store their nodes entirely differently, such as "Node" objects that each already have a reference to a collection of children, rather than graphs stored in a dictionary.

Comment: Can `Funct<T, K>` have "no value" for some input of type `T`, like a `Dictionary`?

Comment: @Kjara If an object has no mappings, then that selector should return an empty sequence.  Given that your dictionary is already storing an empty sequence as the value for that key, the caller need only write `element => foo[element]`.  Of course, if a different caller stores their graph in a different manor entirely, they may call it differently.

Comment: And can `Func<T, K>` be null? (Just checking if I have to change anything in my code regarding invalid input.)

Comment: @Kjara What would you expect this method to do if it were null?  I wouldn't expect it to be able to function if it didn't have a selector, and should therefore fail, but if you feel that there's a sensible output, that's your decision.  What would you expect to happen if a null dictionary was provided in your original method?  If you're asking if delegates are nullable, yes, they are nullable.

Comment: It's not about the dictionary. It's about needing to check for the correctness of input. Whenever I make a method that has some constraints on the input (like, `element` should not be null), I check if they are fulfilled and if they are not, I throw an exception. This way I know that when the method runs without exceptions, I get a reasonable result. And since I couldn't find anywhere if `Func` can be null, I don't know if I have to add a null check for the `Func` in my method.

Comment: @Kjara The easiest way to determine if it's nullable is to try to assign `null` and see what happens.  If it compiles, then it's nullable.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a parameter for the collection type:

```
public static ISet<T> GetClosureSet<T, C>(T element, IDictionary<T, C> elementToCollectionMap) where C : IEnumerable<T> { ... }
```

note the compiler will not be able to infer `C` for you.